# Angular 2 Rendering Performance in a Select

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, asynchronous

We have 2 lists, a short one and a large one. The large one loads the date based on the selection in the short one. 
In the example, most of the elements in the large list are selected (380 out of 400) initially. After a new selection is made in the short list, data in the large list should be cleared and loaded again.

Now the difference lies in the

```
// await this.delayExecution(1);
```

line in the parent component. Uncommenting await (even with 1 ms) changes the execution flow in a way that the second list reacts immediately.

The transpiled code JavaScript:

```
ParentComponent.prototype.selectionChanged = function (data) {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            console.log('waiting');
            this.dataSelectedLarge = [];
            // await this.delayExecution(1);
            this.dataToSetLarge = [];
            console.log('changed');
            return [2 /*return*/];
        });
    });
};
```

And uncommented:

```
ParentComponent.prototype.selectionChanged = function (data) {
return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
    return __generator(this, function (_a) {
        switch (_a.label) {
            case 0:
                console.log('waiting');
                this.dataSelectedLarge = [];
                return [4 /*yield*/, this.delayExecution(1)];
            case 1:
                _a.sent();
                this.dataToSetLarge = [];
                console.log('changed');
                return [2 /*return*/];
        }
    });
    });
};
```

So clearing the selection

```
this.dataSelectedLarge = [];
```

and the data

```
this.dataToSetLarge = [];
```

without some kind of delay forces new rendering of the list which takes long time, while with await rendering happens in an instant.

The example is here: [Angular 2 Performance Select](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Z81UTDBAbuvzvBXf?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

The questions are:

1. why causes this behavior
2. what would be the proper implementation

In the real app, we use *ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush* in the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance problem seems to be the removal of all data AND the selection at the same time, meaning in the same Change Detection Cycle.

After running some experiments with `zones.js`an `NgZone` I figured out, that the only difference is an extra Change Detection between `this.dataSelectedLarge = [];` and   `this.dataToSetLarge = [];`.

By removing the Selection, forcing the Change Detection using injected `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` and removing the Data after that, view gets update immediately and there is not need for `async/wait`.

Finally, the method is as simple as that

```
selectionChanged(data: any) {
  this.dataSelectedLarge = [];
  this.chdRef.detectChanges();
  this.dataToSetLarge = [];
}
```